# Kosovo ISO_N3 or ISO_A3 in Natural Earth

Tags: natural-earth

How does one access Kosovo in the natural earth ne_10m_admin_subunits shapefile? It seems to lack the "XK" code needed to access it.

Answer (score 1):

From an inspection of the file it appears that [Natural Earth](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/) doesn't assign an ISO code for Kosovo (-99 is used). You could find it using any of the following key/value pairs

```
adm0_a3_us  KOS
sov_a3      KOS
adm0_a3     KOS
gu_a3       KOS
```

I suspect it is related to the note `Self admin.; Claimed by Serbia` and the there is further discussion at  http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-cultural-vectors/10m-admin-0-details/